# wxpython panel fullscreen?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to make my top_panel of my program go into fullscreen only, i hope to have a button which will do this, the issue i am faced with is i dont know how to make the panel go into fullscreen it self without forcing the whole frame to go into fullscreen using ShowFullscreen(true)

i hope you can help me

```
class top_panel(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent, size=(400,175))
    self.SetBackgroundColour('BLACK')
    self.ofullscreen = wx.Button(self, -1, "Fullscreen", (10,30))
    self.ofullscreen.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onfullscreen, self.ofullscreen)
    self.gbs = wx.GridBagSizer(2,2)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKey)
    wx.Frame.ShowFullScreen(True)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onKey(self, event):
    """
    Check for ESC key press and exit is ESC is pressed
    """
    key_code = event.GetKeyCode()
    if key_code == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
        self.GetParent().Close()
    else:
        event.Skip()   

def onfullscreen(self):
    print "hola"
    #self.fullscreen?????
```

Comment: you have a main frame and then on some event you display the panel and want it to become a full screen? did you try it? what issue did you have? maybe this feature available only for the TLW? please post a backtrace from running your script.

Answer (score 3):

I have written about this subject on my blog. Here's an example:

```
import wx


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKey)

    def onKey(self, event):
        """
        Check for ESC key press and exit is ESC is pressed
        """
        key_code = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key_code == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.GetParent().Close()
        else:
            event.Skip()


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test FullScreen")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I have noticed that this code doesn't seem to work with Macs.

Comment: I did happen to see your post however the issue is I only want to one single panel to go full screen as I have 3 in my frame and I only want it executed once I double left click

Comment: I would just bind the double-click event to that panel then. When someone double-clicks it, you can open a new frame full-screen. It won't be the same panel, but it will look like it was.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up making a new .py and created a new frame and panel so once a video file is selected the new .py will open, and within the new panel I've set it that a function inside the frame that checks if it's full screen or not and sets it to its according settings. And just I made a bind within the panel which works on a double left click and then it's linked to a parent.onFullScreen function I made within my new frame

Answer (score 1):

Using Mike Driscoll's example code, there is a way of faking full screen for a panel, when more than one panel is being used. It's a bit of a hack at the moment but it should give you the gist of it.
Use `SetMinSize` and `SendSizeEvent`.
Click on a coloured panel for focus and then press F1,F2 or F3 to swap the panels in and out of "full screen" or revert to equal sizes.

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKey)

    def onKey(self, event):
        """
        Check for ESC key press and exit is ESC is pressed
        F1 panel 1 is full screen
        F2 panel 2 is full screen
        F3 panels revert to equal sizes
        """
        key_code = event.GetKeyCode()
        parent = self.GetParent()
        width, height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        if key_code == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.GetParent().Close()
        elif key_code == wx.WXK_F1: 
            parent.panel1.SetMinSize((1,1))
            parent.panel2.SetMinSize((width,height))
            parent.SendSizeEvent()
            parent.Layout()
            parent.Fit()
        elif key_code == wx.WXK_F2: 
            parent.panel2.SetMinSize((1,1))
            parent.panel1.SetMinSize((width,height))
            parent.SendSizeEvent()
            parent.Layout()
            parent.Fit()
        elif key_code == wx.WXK_F3: 
            parent.panel2.SetMinSize((120,70))
            parent.panel1.SetMinSize((120,70))
            parent.SendSizeEvent()
            parent.Layout()
            parent.Fit()
        else:
            event.Skip()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test FullScreen")
        self.panel1 = MyPanel(self)
        self.panel2 = MyPanel(self)
        self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)
        self.panel2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.panel1)
        vbox.Add(self.panel2)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note: for your case you will not want to really go to full screen, as you will probably need to still access some control buttons, so just deduct the amount you need from the full screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show a child window, such as a panel, full screen. Only top level frames can be shown full screen but, of course, this shouldn't be a problem at all because absolutely nothing prevents you from creating a frame containing just the panel and then showing this frame full screen is completely equivalent to showing the panel full screen.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this first and will reply how it goes

Comment: I have tried it and it didn't work as I wanted to I decided to create a whole new .py containing a new frame etc and only execute it once a recognisable file extension is found for video only